# how to compare two dgv and pass datagridview to another Form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridview that each contain two columns and the same numbers of rows.I compared these two datagridview using this loop :

```
 int result = 0;
 for (int i=0;i< dgvInvent1.RowCount;i++)
 {
   var src1 = dgvInvent1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   var src2 = dgvInvent2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   result = Int32.Parse(src1) - Int32.Parse(src2);
 }
```

I want to transfer the result to another datagridview too, I named it "dgvFinal" , except that dvgFinal is in another form called "Form2" that I just created , so i added this line to form2

```
public DataGridView dvgFinal { get; set; }
```

and in my main Form i added to my loop

```
Form2 re = new Form2();
            int result = 0;
            for (int i=0;i< dgvInvent1.RowCount;i++)
            {
                var src1 = dgvInvent1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                var src2 = dgvInvent2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                 result = Int32.Parse(src1) - Int32.Parse(src2);
                re.dvgFinal.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = result;
            }
```

but it doesn't work , i get

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

someone could help me ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you have 2 dgv with same columns and rows and you have to subtract column 1 from `dgvInvent1` to `dgvInvent2` and display result in third dgv that is on another from, right?

Comment: yes yes exactly

Comment: Does 'dvgFinal' have as many rows (and at least three columns) as 'dgvInvent1' at the time you execute this loop?

Comment: No , 'dvgFinal' does not contain any data just columns that I have predefined

Comment: Why wouldn't you work with the Datasource instead?

Comment: Why in the world you convert the values ToString() and do an Int32.Parse!!! Why not directly use the Value???

Comment: how to transfer then the result with datasource?

Comment: if dgvFinal has know rows, then why you are accessing its rows? AAlso make sure the dgvFinal  is not null

Comment: @CetinBasoz sorry i am beginner in C# :D

Comment: You didn't even tell us what your datasource is. How do you get the data into Datagrid1 and 2 in the first place?

Comment: i get the data from mysql database

Comment: Oh Kevin, getting information from you is very hard. How do you do that? There are N ways you know, don't you? If you are getting it from the database, why wouldn't you simply get the 3rd from database is very questionable.

Comment: i use Datasource to load the data ,  dgvInvent1.DataSource = db.query("SELECT idMarq , nomMarq FROM marques");

Comment: What is db.query? At least tell us what it returns?

Comment: @CetinBasoz its returns Datatable

Comment: OK then it has a DataRow collection that you can query with Linq. Simply query and select into a datatable for 3rd grid. I will soon post a sample (mine would be from SQL server as a sample, but doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

```
Form2 re = new Form2();
int result = 0;
for (int i=0 ;i< dgvInvent1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var src1 = (int)dgvInvent1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    var src2 = (int)dgvInvent2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    result = src1 - src2;
    re.dvgFinal.Rows.Add(result.ToString());
}
```

This should work for you. The reason is that you try to access rows that aren't there yet.

However, consider using Datasource instead.

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object'

Comment: @kevin73 see my edited answer. You need to cast the value of the cells to `int` before performing operations on them.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe `code`

Comment: re.dvgFinal.Rows.Add(result.ToString()); last line

Comment: This means that the form isn't initialized yet. dvgFinal is still `null`. You need to run this code after the form is initialized.

Comment: I added Form2 re = new Form(); before my loop and next re.Show(); after the loop

Comment: @kevin73 That doesn't mean the form is initialized. Make sure `InitializeComponent()` is called in the Form2 constructor.

Comment: @kevin73 call re.Show() before running the loop.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε same when i show the form before the loop it's same error message

Comment: @ViggoLundén it doesn't work i wonder if it's because it's not about "public" or "private" problem

Comment: .Show() is not needed before anyway.

Comment: @CetinBasoz What do you mean *.Show() is not needed before anyway.*

Comment: @kevin73 In your Form2 constructor after *InitializeComponent()* you need to create the *dvgFinal* with all columns and rows and add it in form2: *this.Controls.Add( dvgFinal);*

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε, not having .Show() before accessing to DataGridView in another Form is perfectly fine I mean. You could even do that without showing the form at all.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use `DataTable` to load all your results like.

```
Form5 re = new Form5();
int result = 0;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Result");

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    var src1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    var src2 = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    result = Convert.ToInt32(src1) - Convert.ToInt32(src2);

    row["Result"] = result;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

}

re.DataTable = dt;
re.Show();
```

2) Create a new public property of `DataTable` on target form so we can access it from our source form like

```
public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }
```

3) Add one `DataGridView` from toolbox or from code to target form like `dgvFinal`.

If you want to manually add column to your `dgvFinal` then set it ColumnType to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and DataPropertyName to `Result` from property window.

4) Add `Form_Load` method to your target form and assign `DataSource`

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dgvFinal.DataSource = DataTable;
}
```

**Output:**

Source Form

[image]

Target Form

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to set custome header name for each of your column in datagridview then set 
`HeaderText` value.

In this case the datagridview is your `dgvFinal`

Select datagridview => open property window => choose columns property => choose your desired column => choose and set `HeaderText` value.

If you want to add more columns in your dgvFinal then you can add repective columns in your datatable in point no 1 listed above like

```
dt.Columns.Add("Result1");
dt.Columns.Add("Result2");
dt.Columns.Add("Result3");
```

And in for loop you can assign rows value to each of your column like

```
result1 = Convert.ToInt32(src1) - Convert.ToInt32(src2);
result2 = Convert.ToInt32(src1) + Convert.ToInt32(src2);
result3 = Convert.ToInt32(src1) * Convert.ToInt32(src2);

row["Result1"] = result1;
row["Result2"] = result2;
row["Result3"] = result3;
```

You may assign any values to each of your row, it may be from your `dgvInvent1` or from `dgvInvent2` or any of your calculated values.

And finally set `HeaderText` values for each of your above column
in `dgvFinal`

Comment: Can you give us a reference that backs up the statement "DataTable is always best to use as DataSource to DataGridView"? Who said that?

Comment: this is my personal experience that I almost use `DataTable` as binding with `DataGridView` bcoz most of my projects its suitable, If you don't want this line then I'll remove it

Comment: @ershoaib The 'result' column does not belong to the table. But i just changed it in my form , or maybe it's another ?

Comment: @kevin73, where did u got this error? If you got this error on target form's `datagridview` then remove columns from it if you have only one column in this `datagridview`

Comment: @kevin73, I made some updates to answer please view those changes carefully :)

Comment: @ershoaib it works now , thank you. I just tried it. But i'd like too copy all column first to display names with result now

Comment: @kevin73, could you pease elaborate this => But i'd like too copy all column first to display names with result now , so I'll can update answer :)

Comment: @kevin73, view the edit section in answer might be it help you for your last comment, if it help then accept answer or let me know  .

Comment: @ershoaib i want filliing a datagridview column without using a loop , possile ?

Comment: but you have to do some calculation of `result = Convert.ToInt32(src1) - Convert.ToInt32(src2);` that is from both datagridview so you must to loop through on it., If you have to just copy both of datagridview column without any calculation then it will possible too.

Comment: @kevin73, is there any issue regarding answer. from my point of view i tried to gave you an answer that you ask question for. and your said `it works now , thank you.` but you asked some extended scenario in later comment that would be fit in new question. my suggestion is to ask new question with those extended scenario so other user will help you upon it. finally its your choice to accept or unaccept this answer. or you want more help from me let me know

Comment: @ershoaib don't worry bro all is okay , i added new feature to my code to make color base on values , thank you again :)

Comment: Glad to hear, if my answer really help you then please accept it and vote up. I'd already voted up to your question   :)

Comment: If you face any issue or error while adding your new feature then post a new question and ping me url of that question here in comment then I'll definitely help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working sample:

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
    {
        string query = @"with myTally (N) as (
             select top(10) row_number() over (order by t1.object_id)
             from sys.all_columns t1 
             cross join sys.all_columns t2)
             select cast(N * 1000 * rand() as int) as col1, cast(N * 100 * rand() as int) as col2
             from myTally";
             con.Open();
        tbl1.Load(new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader());
        tbl2.Load(new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader());
    }

    Form f1 = new Form();
    var dgv1 = new DataGridView { Top = 10, Left = 10, Height = 100, DataSource = tbl1 };
    var dgv2 = new DataGridView { Top = 130, Left = 10, Height = 100, DataSource = tbl2 };
    var btn = new Button {Top=250, Left=10, Text="Show 3rd Grid"};

    f1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {dgv1, dgv2, btn});

    btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        DataTable tbl3 = new DataTable();
        tbl3.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < tbl1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            tbl3.Rows.Add((int)tbl1.Rows[i]["col1"] - (int)tbl2.Rows[i]["col1"]);
        }

        Form f2 = new Form();
        var dgv3 = new DataGridView {Dock=DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=tbl3};
        f2.Controls.Add(dgv3);
        f2.ShowDialog();
    };

    f1.Show();
}
```